# return statement and exception in try block in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(method());
    }

    public static int method() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 2;
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

in this problem try block has return statement and throws exception also...
its output is COMPILER ERROR....

we know that finally block overrides the return or exception statement in try/catch block...
but this problem has both in try block...
why the output is error ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us the actual compiler error? Although this is a fairly trivial case, in general you decrease your chances of getting good answers by posting incomplete/ambiguous questions.

Answer (score 14):

Because your `return` statement is unreachable - the execution flow can never reach that line.

If the `throw` statement was in an `if`-clause, then the `return` would be potentially reachable and the error would be gone. But in this case it doesn't make sense to have `return` there.

Another important note - avoid returning from the `finally` clause. Eclipse compiler, for example, shows a warning about a return statement in the `finally` clause.

Comment: very well put. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 6):

The compiler exception come from, like my Eclipse dude says

```
Unreachable code    Test2.java  line 11 Java Problem
```

The return statement of your main code block will never be reached, as an exception is thrown before.

Alos notice the return statement of your finally block is, at least, a design flaw, like Eclipse once again says

```
 finally block does not complete normally   Test2.javajava  line 14 Java Problem
```

Indeed, as a finally block is only here to provide some clean closing, it is not expected to return something that would override the result normally returned by the method.

Comment: +1. I understand you wanted to say "design flaw" instead of "design law" :)

Answer (score 2):

The `throw new Exception()` will be called no matter what, so anything within the `try` block that follows the `throw` is Unreachable Code. Hence the Error.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(method());
    }

    public static int method() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
            return 1; //<<< This is unreachable 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 2;
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

It should eventually return 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'return' keyword within try block is unreachable, that's why you are getting compile-time error. Omit that 'return' keyword from try block, and then run your program, your will successfully compile.